# why sort in python is not working?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
code:
list=['1','85863','432','93','549834']
list.sort()
print (list)

Actual output:
>>> 
['1', '432', '549834', '85863', '93']
#why sort is not working
Expected output:
['1','93','432','83863','549834']
```

I have tried other sort operations also but they are displaying same output.
when i tried to read list from keyboard input they are reading only strings but not int please help me why?

Comment: Why do you expect that sort order?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python

Comment: Your expected output is sorted neither alphabetically nor numerically.

Comment: that looks sorted to me. (contrary to your expected output, for which I can't find any sorting logic. except by sum of the digits, maybe?)

Comment: You can compile brain teasers from some of these downvoted questions you see on SO

Comment: Fortunately, SO's mechanical Turk is good at brute-forcing these brain teasers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i tried to read list from keyboard input they are reading only strings but not int please help me why

if `x` is a string, just use `int(x)` to convert to `int`

You're sorting strings (text), not by numerical values like integers

For your expected output you have to convert to ints first

```
my_list= ['1','85863','432','93','549834']
my_list = [int(x) for x in my_list]
```

Now you can sort numerically, and get a list of ints

```
my_list.sort()
```

<sub>**N.B.** avoid using `list` as variable name, it is a Python built-in</sub>

Comment: His expected output isn't in numerical order either.

Comment: Hmm yeah also not clear if expected output is a list of ints or strings again

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to sort by the sum to match your expected output:

```
l = ['1','85863','432','93','549834']

l.sort(key=lambda x: sum(map(int,x)))

print(l)
['1', '432', '93', '83863', '549834']
```

Comment: Ha! nice pattern guessing going on!

Comment: @bakkal, it is the only thing that makes any sense, sorting by length,last digit,  first digit or anything else would not give the expected output

Comment: Oh I liked your solution, let's just hope the OP just didn't screwed up the expected output just like they screwed the question :P

Comment: @bakkal, that is a distinct possibility!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert the strings to int.

```
list = [int(ele) for ele in list]
list.sort()
print list
```

Answer (score 0):

Without int:

```
lst = ['1','85863','432','93','549834']
lst.sort()
lst.sort(key=len)
print(lst)
```

This give:

```
['1', '93', '432', '85863', '549834']
```

And if you want integers…

```
my_int = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply missed the logic of converting a string into int.By default python input will be taken as a string. so,we can use any method mentioned in the answers to convert in to string and then `sort()` method works succesufully over int